# Google Analytics view all raw requests

Tags: google-analytics

Is there an place to view all raw request received for a `Tag` in `Google Analytics`; send though `Measurement Protocol`

For example if the request is

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tid=UA-12345-67&ea=Purchase&el=Code1&v=1&t=event&ec=OrderBook&cid=0eshxa2zyhqyt3hw54w1qxwn&dp=OrderBook.aspx
```

see the exact raw request in `Google Analytics`

Comment: what tracking you have pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot see raw data in Google Analytics, it shows aggregated data only.

In a GA36 account you could use a BigQuery integration to access raw data (although not as a continous string but broken up in single fields), but GA36 comes with a hefty price tag.

If you are creating the requests yourself your best bet would be to write your own logger that stores every request before it goes to GA.